# AWS OpenSearch client error: unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

I am trying to write a lambda to get data from OpenSearach domain.

```js
const { Client } = require('@opensearch-project/opensearch');
const { createAWSConnection, awsGetCredentials } = require('@acuris/aws-es-connection');

const test = async () => {

    const awsCredentials = await awsGetCredentials();
    const AWSConnection = createAWSConnection(awsCredentials);
    const client = new Client({
        ...AWSConnection,
        node: 'https://<domain-name>.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com'
    });

    // inside async func
    await client.cat.help();
};
test();
```

Error:

```
(node:32926) ProductNotSupportedSecurityError: The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch due to security privileges on the server-side. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product.
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I haven't tested any of the answers yet, working with rest apis for now...

Comment: Okay. Did you try creating a user on AWS and adding that user to a group that has aws elasticsearch access policy? That's the right credential to use.

Comment: If u r using fine-grained access control u can refer to this blog: https://www.antstack.io/blog/getting-started-with-open-search or for regular access yes, IAM permissions would work,

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same error but I used @elasticsearch lib instead of @opensearch-project. Maybe you can try it too.
Error was resolved by downgrading @elasticsearch lib version.

Comment: can u tell the version u used?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Elasticsearch client version 7.13.0.
According to the [docs](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/index/), it is the latest Elasticsearch client that is compatible with OpenSearch.